# Random print program, prints multiple outputs at once despite sleep() function?

Tags: c++, terminal, console, sleep, usleep

So, I have the program below. What it does is, it prints random numbers while formating them with a width of 10 on the console.

Now, when I added the sleep function, I expected it to print one number every 10 milliseconds (or more), but what it does is, it prints 100 outputs every 100*10 milliseconds. I was wondering, why does this happen? Does the output get buffered or what?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        usleep(10*1000);    // No matter the input, the same thing happens
        cout << setw(10) << rand()%(90*i) + 10*i;
    }
}
```

I tried this both on windows and unix and it's the exact same thing.

Comment: Yes, the output does get buffered. Either explicitly `flush()` or `<< std::endl;`.

Comment: @hmjd So, when after collecting 102 outputs the system decides to ouput? When I add `<< endl;` every number gets printed correctly, but on a new line. How would I go about printing it the same way but formatted?(Every number on its own, in the same line)

Comment: `std::cout.flush()` will avoid the newline.

Comment: OK, I solved it by adding `cout.flush();` after printing. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the output does get buffered.

Use `std::cout.flush();` to flush manually.

As a note, `std::endl` (appends a new line and) does the flush.